# UITableView with fading cells on top and bottom - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need my table view to fade its top and bottom cells as it is scrolled. I have tried some solutions involving gradient and masks but non of it worked, the gradient from clear to white has a black tint. Does anyone has a solution to accomplish that in swift?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired effect by using some methods defined in `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. First thing you need to know that cell main subview is `contentView` add all other subviews are subviews of it. What you need to do is to set `contentView` alpha to 0 in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath:` method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Fade Cell"
        cell.contentView.alpha = 0 // Here we set the alpha of the content view
        return cell
    }
```

If you run your application now, you would have plain white cells. Only thing we need now is to know when cells are displayed, so we can show `contentView`. Second `UITableViewDelegate` protocol method comes in handy now.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
            cell.contentView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
```

This delegate method is called when cells are preparing to be displayed, and it's the perfect place to animate `contentView` alpha property to 1.

Comment: It didn't exactly work, but you gave some ideas, thank you, i'll post my progress.